# How can I move up one of the settings in my.settings?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I wanted to move up one of the settings inside my.settings so I can easily view them, for example I wanted to make all database related settings close to one another.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Delete the higher settings to make space and then recreate them.
2. Hand-edit your *.vbproj project file. It's just a text xml file. You should be able to find where the settings are listed and put them in whatever order you want. I would expect Visual Studio to list them in that order.

Comment: Thank you so much, regarding your 2nd option I check my `TCP_Client.vbproj` and `TCP_Client.vbproj.user` but I can't find my settings, but when I check the `Settings.settings` under `My Project` I saw it.